# Lightswitch (1st version - Silverlight) - Close Form

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm working with Lightswitch (the 1st version - Silverlight). Actually, I never used it before, but I have been assigned to make a couple of small changes.

I added a "New Data Screen" which is tied to a newly created table. I have some code on the inserting event of the table to call a sproc using the values inputted into the new table as parameters to the sproc. That all works.

How do you programattically close the screen after the user clicks the save button and after my inserting event finishes?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I just did a this.Close(false) and the Saved() event of the screen.